# Importing project with Support library - package android.support... does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, android-support-library

I'm trying to import the following project from a Google CodeLab.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-codelab-android/blob/master/codelab.md

But when I try to build the project I get the error:

```
java: package android.support.v4.view does not exist
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MotionEventCompat
  location: class de.timroes.swipetodismiss.SwipeDismissList
java: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MotionEventCompat
  location: class de.timroes.swipetodismiss.SwipeDismissList
```

I expect that if I solve the first one, the others will be solved too.
However I can't seem to resolve it.

The tutorial of the codelab says that if it fails, you should check the SDK manager and install the support repository, which I did. But I still get the error.
[image: screenshot to show that I installed support]

I tried to restart android studio and recreating the project etc for several times. I even reintalled Android Studio and now have android studio version 5.2 . I have this same issue on my Ubuntu VM as well as on my Windows machine, so two seperate environments.

Also I see problems in my project structure, but don't know how to solve it.
[image: Problem in project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to sync Gradle in Android Studio after importing the project.